# forward declaration of a class template including a namespace causes compile-error

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, namespaces, forward-declaration

I have an example1 and an example2, which uses a forward declaration of a class template prefixed with the namespace of the corresponding class template. The first example compiles fine with visual-studio, while the second example does not. I checked the both examples against other compilers (http://rextester.com). Now I have 2 questions:

- Using here a namespace in the forward declaration seems to be illegal. Why exactly?
- Visual studio (2015 and 2017) seems to allow the forward declaration with the additional namespace in the **first** example, but in the second example not. Is this a bug?

**Example 1:**

```
#include <vector>

namespace N1
{
    template <typename T> struct MySystem {};
    template <typename T> class Other {};

    struct MyClass
    {
        MyClass() { typename Dependencies::TYPE_A oTYPE_A; }

        struct Dependencies
        {
            template <typename>
            class N1::Other;

            struct TypeX_Dependencies;

            using TYPE_A = N1::MySystem<N1::Other<TypeX_Dependencies>>;

            struct TypeX_Dependencies
            {
                using TYPE_A = typename Dependencies::TYPE_A;
            };

            using TYPE_X = N1::Other<TypeX_Dependencies>;
        };
    };
}

int main(){ return 0; }
```

c++  (gcc 5.4.0)
`source_file.cpp:15:23: error: invalid use of template-name ‘N1::Other’ without an argument list class N1::Other;`

c++ (clang 3.8.0)
`source_file.cpp:15:23: error: non-friend class member 'Other' cannot have a qualified name class N1::Other;

source_file.cpp:15:19: error: forward declaration of class cannot have a nested name specifier class N1::Other;`

c++ (vc++ 19.00.23506 for x64 / also vs community 2017 15.4.4)
`compiles fine`

**Example 2:**

```
#include <vector>

namespace N1
{
    template <typename T> struct MySystem {};
    template <typename T> class Other {};

    template <typename T>
    struct MyClass
    {
        MyClass() { typename Dependencies::TYPE_A oTYPE_A; }

        struct Dependencies
        {
            template <typename>
            class N1::Other;

            struct TypeX_Dependencies;

            using TYPE_A = N1::MySystem<N1::Other<TypeX_Dependencies>>;

            struct TypeX_Dependencies
            {
                using TYPE_A = typename Dependencies::TYPE_A;
            };

            using TYPE_X = N1::Other<TypeX_Dependencies>;
        };
    };
}

int main(){ return 0; }
```

c++  (gcc 5.4.0)
`source_file.cpp:16:23: error: invalid use of template-name ‘N1::Other’ without an argument list class N1::Other;`

c++ (clang 3.8.0)
`source_file.cpp:16:23: error: non-friend class member 'Other' cannot have a qualified name class N1::Other;

source_file.cpp:16:19: error: forward declaration of class cannot have a nested name specifier class N1::Other;`

c++ (vc++ 19.00.23506 for x64 / also vs community 2017 15.4.4)
`source_file.cpp(16): error C3855: 'N1::Other': template parameter 'T' is incompatible with the declaration

source_file.cpp(24): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'N1::MyClass<T>::Dependencies' being compiled

source_file.cpp(29): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'N1::MyClass<T>' being compiled

source_file.cpp(20): error C3203: 'Other': unspecialized class template can't be used as a template argument for template parameter 'T', expected a real type`

Comment: Use `Other<T>` for it to work

Comment: Is the `Other` declared in `struct Dependencies` supposed to be a new class, or does it refer to the global `::N1::Other` class?

Comment: [Compiles for me](http://rextester.com/YXXHEH87078). Anyway, why do you feel the need to redeclare `Other` inside `Dependencies` in the first place?

Comment: Put "typename" in front of "Dependencies".

Comment: The first one compiles under 15.5.2.

Comment: I have improved/changed the question and code. Maybe now you can understand my question better. @1201ProgramAlarm: 'Other' should refer to the global ::N1::Other class.

Comment: So what you'd really want to do is `class ::N1::Other`, but since that class is already visible you don't need that declaration at all.  Your current declaration is trying to refer to a (nonexistent) `::N1::MyClass::N1::Other` class.

Comment: Ok I understand that I don't need the declaration at all. Also here exist a bug in the vc++-compiler, which allow my false declaration (in example 1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a bug.

According to [[dcl.type.elab]/1](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.elab#1),

> ... If an [*elaborated-type-specifier*](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.elab#nt:elaborated-type-specifier) is the sole constituent of a declaration, the declaration is ill-formed unless it is an explicit specialization, an explicit instantiation or it has one of the following forms:
>
> - ***class-key attribute-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub> identifier*** ;
> - `friend` *class-key* `::`<sub>*opt*</sub> *identifier* ;
> - `friend` *class-key* `::`<sub>*opt*</sub> *simple-template-id* ;
> - `friend` *class-key nested-name-specifier identifier* ;
> - `friend` *class-key nested-name-specifier* `template`<sub>*opt*</sub> *simple-template-id* ;

your declaration `class N1::Other` is neither an explicit specialization, nor an explicit instantiation, so it has to have the emphasized form (ignoring those `friend` declaration). Note no [*nested-name-specifier*](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.id.qual#nt:nested-name-specifier) is allowed before *identifier* in the emphasized form, so the declaration is ill-formed. The compiler error of Clang in the following example without template shows this problem.

```
namespace N {
    struct S;
}
struct N::S; // error: forward declaration of struct cannot have a nested name specifier
```

[LIVE EXAMPLE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/vYivUwXYTUWvXfmU) (BTW, GCC accepts this code and just gives a warning about nothing new to be declared. I guess it is a bug of GCC.)

Here the  [*template-head*](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/temp#nt:template-head) `template <typename>` does not help, because `class N1::Other` itself should form a *declaration* according to the grammar definition of *template-head*, thus the paragragh above applies.

Roughly speaking, a declaration for class in different scope from the scope where a class with the same name is declared should either introduce a new class, in which case *nested-name-specifier* should not be used, or define the  previously declared class, in which case the grammar forms a [*class-specifier*](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/class#nt:class-specifier) rather than an *elaborated-type-specifier*, thus the paragraph above does not apply. As a conclusion, this rule is reasonable.